# root user does not exists

Tags: postgresql

after creating db in docker with:

```
docker run  -it  \
  -e POSTGRES_USER="root" \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD="root" \
  -e POSTGRES_DB="ny_taxi" \
  -v /Users/ruslanpilipyuk/Desktop/data-engineering-zoomcamp-main/week_1_basics_n_setup/2_docker_sql/ny_taxi_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
  -p 5432:5432 \
  postgres:13
```

But when I try to connect to it for example with sqlalchemy, I get this:

```
OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist

(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

Same error happens when using pgcli to connect with.

```
(base) ruslanpilipyuk@MacBook-Pro-Ruslan 2_docker_sql % pgcli -h localhost -p 5432 -u root -d ny_taxi
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

I have used also, standard superuser `postgres`, and it is not working either with same error:

```
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
```

Comment: You need to find out what the main user name is in your postgres database.  Apparently, it's not "root".

Comment: This is not `MySQL` there is not a `root` user. Generally the installed superuser is `postgres`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver it does not work either with postgres

Comment: How did you install Postgres? What was the error message when you used `postgres` user. Add information as update to question.

Comment: In your final attempt, the error message clearly says 'root' still.  So whatever you did to attempt to change it to postgres was not effective.

Comment: remove double quotes from username and password       docker run  -it    -e POSTGRES_USER=root   -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root   -e POSTGRES_DB=ny_taxi   -v ~/home/test:/var/lib/postgresql/data   -p 5432:5432   postgres:13    works well

Comment: You still have not said how you installed Postgres?